# Problems to get functions argument outside the scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get functions argument outside the scope, but have some kinds of problems to do that.

I have tried to get the value by this code: `var text = $.commentString.text();`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/10/)

JQuery:

```
function addComment(commentString) {

    var container = $('#divComments');
    var inputs = container.find('label');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    var div = $('<div />', {
        class: 'CommentStyle'
    });

    $('<label />', {
        id: 'comment' + id,
        text: commentString
    }).appendTo(div);


    var $edit = $('<p />', {
        class: 'edit',
        text: 'Edit'
    }).addClass('edit').appendTo(div);

    div.appendTo(container);

}

$('#divComments').on('click','.edit',function () {
    var text = $.commentString.text();
});
```

Comment: what is `$.commentString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript it's not possible to get access to a variable outside of the scope which it was declared in. You could declare the variable outside of your function, but it will be overwritten every time the function runs - it doesn't look like this is the behaviour you're after.

What you can do in this example is use jQuery to traverse the DOM and find the text which you require.

```
$('#divComments').on('click','.edit',function () {
  var text = $(this).parents(".CommentStyle").find("label").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

then just declare a variable outside the function:

```
var someCommentString;

function addComment(commentString) {
    someCommentString = commentString;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

or u can try other way to get value but not sure its correct or not

```
$('#divComments').on('click','.edit',function () {
$(this).prev().text()
});
```